# Requirements for successful WIFI sniffing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sniffing

I want to know what conditions have to be met that WIFI sniffing is easy possible. Normally, you have a WPA2 encryption, but the question is if this is enough. To my questions:

1. Who can sniff the WIFI network when a WPA2 encryption is active? All user who are on the same network (WIFI, LAN)? So on WIFI only if everybody has the same WPA2 key?
2. What if each user needs some special login data so he can access the WIFI network (seen in company networks)? Would such a user also be able to sniff the WIFI packets? Or is this per user?

Of course if someone is able to find out the WPA2 key and all on the WIFI network are using the same key an intruder can sniff the network. Also if there is a MAC filtering active it is harder for the intruder. But which else conditions have to be met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your network is using "WPA-Personal" WPA/WPA2 encryption (typical for home networks), then, in order to capture traffic, you would need:

1. Wi-Fi hardware that supports monitor mode (or otherwise supports capturing all traffic that the radio receives, such as an AirPcap adapter);
2. software that, on your OS, can run that hardware in monitor mode and capture traffic;

and to decrypt that traffic, you would need:

1. a program that can decrypt WPA/WPA2 traffic, such as Wireshark;
2. the key for the network;
3. the initial "EAPOL handshakes" for *each* device whose traffic you want to decrypt.

The third item in that list is the tricky part - that handshake is the "initial registration" referred to by user236012, and, if you don't happen to capture that, you can't decrypt WPA/WPA2 traffic.  (If you *do* capture it, even with another host, and you have the key and a program that can decrypt WPA/WPA2 traffic, you can decrypt it.)  Those are typically sent when machines initially join the network or re-join the network after waking up, although [there are ways of forcing machines to re-authenticate](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa#step_3_-_use_aireplay-ng_to_deauthenticate_the_wireless_client).  And, if you don't have the key, but do have the handshake captured, you can do a dictionary attack to try to find the key; try doing a Web search for "cracking WPA2" for more information.

Wireshark currently doesn't support "WPA-Enterprise"; I don't know whether that's just a Simple Matter Of Programming or whether there are inherent difficulties with it (e.g., getting relevant information from a RADIUS server).  Corporate networks might use that; home and small business networks probably don't.  (Your question 2 is probably about WPA-Enterprise.)

[Wi-Fi Protected Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup) apparently has a "feature" that makes it easier to crack WPA/WPA2 networks.

So, if you manage to capture the EAPOL handshake, you can decrypt the traffic if you have the key, and possibly find the key if you don't have the key.  A WPA-Personal network is safe against casual sniffing, but, unless your password is hard to crack with a dictionary attack, it's not safe against the determined cracker.

Comment: If someone has access to the same ethernet LAN, on which the WIFI router operates, sniffing is possible without cracking something? So it would be the task of the network admin to use MAC filtering everywhere and detect LAN sniffer?

Comment: If the Wi-Fi packets are being forwarded (bridging or routing) to a wired LAN, and you have access to the wired LAN (and it's not switched or you can somehow get the switch to send you third-party traffic), yes, sniffing those Wi-Fi packets will get you un-encrypted packets.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi is basically signals transmitted over air. So, everybody who is "close enough" to a sender (like each host connected to wifi as well as routers) can sniff packets, i.e., the signal (of course, he needs appropriate hardware, which is for example a wifi stick).

There is no need to be part of the network.

If the data is sent unencrypted over wifi, the sniffer immediately can read what has been sent. However, encryption like wpa2 is used, the captured data looks like random bits to the sniffer, so he has to decrypt it first, which means, he knows the passphrase. Or he tries to crack it.

Edit: Hosts on the same network are not capable of sniffing data from other hosts. Although all host share the same key, this key is only used for "initial registration" between the host and the router/access point. Once this connection is established, the router and a host agree on a different secret key, which is unique between the host and the accesspoint each.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I can't up vote you because I don't have enough rep for that (min. 15). Someone sitting on the same LAN as the router would be able to sniff all packets? So the main problem are networks which are unencrypted (e.g. public hotspots). All other are relatively "save"? How much would be the benefit of an additional SSL encryption in addition to a WIFI encryption?